# How to show text (string) of a query in fusion table?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables, bus

I'm creating a map of bus lines and i have a query that display multiple polylines on a map (Fusion Table). I want to display the name of each polyline in text(string) on the page. It could be any form: infowindow, sidebar,only text.

```
query: 
{
    select: 'geometry',
    from: 'tableid',
    where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(-8.754864219111248, -63.87663083648681), 200))' 
}
```

I was looking for some examples but i didnt understand how to export the name of the polyline to text form:
[example 1](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_closestPlaces.html)
[example 2](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linkto.html?filename=cta.xml)

Comment: display when? Without any user-action or e.g. when a user clicks on the polyline?

Comment: The query show all the polylines and under the map it shows the text (name of polylines) without clicks.

Comment: This can't be done via a FusionTablesLayer, you must request the data separately. See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/fusiontables or https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select